# Is there an way through we can fetch data from neo4j database based on different conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (a:Chemical{name:'abc'})-[r:On_Reacting_With]->(b:Chemical)
WHERE r.outputtime >'20'
RETURN count(b)
```

As in the above query I can get values where the `outputtime` is greater than 20. But I want to give the user a feature where he/she can fetch the data where `outoutime` can be greater, lesser or equal to a value. I want to know how can we pass the operator as params in code.

Answer (score 0):

*Aside: using string values for time comparison will not produce correct results unless all strings have the same length (including leading zero characters, as needed).*

You can pass in an `operator` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) and use a `CASE` clause. For instance:

```
MATCH (a:Chemical{name:'abc'})-[r:On_Reacting_With]->(b:Chemical)
WHERE
  CASE $operator
    WHEN '<' THEN r.outputtime < '20'
    WHEN '>' THEN r.outputtime > '20'
    ELSE r.outputtime = '20'
  END
RETURN COUNT(b)
```